# Can't find model associated model data

Tags: cakephp, recursion, model, relationship

i'm new in CakePHP and i'm having problems in an example i'm building to learn.

I'm building a plugin with 3 models (Categoria,Plato,Imagen)

The relationships between them are the following:
Categoria - Plato (n-n)
Plato - Imagen (1-n)

If I go to Plato view, I get all Imagen by the relationship, but when I access through a category, I can't just reach the Imagen associated with each Plato. Why? What's the problem?

Models code:

Plato:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Plato extends ErestaurantAppModel {   
    public $name = 'Plato';
    //public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Categoria' => array(
            'className' => 'Categoria',
            'joinTable' => 'categorias_platos',
            'foreignKey' => 'plato_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'categoria_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
        )
    );
    public $hasMany = array('Imagen' =>
                            array('foreingkey' => array('plato_id')));
}
```

Categoria:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Categoria extends ErestaurantAppModel {
    public $name = 'Categoria';
    //public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Plato' => array(
            'className' => 'Plato',
            'joinTable' => 'categorias_platos',
            'foreignKey' => 'categoria_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'plato_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
        )
    );
}
```

Imagen:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Imagen extends ErestaurantAppModel {  
    public $name = 'Imagen';
    //public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo = array('Plato');
}
```

Finally, the code I'm launching when i go to a Categoria view.

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class CategoriasController extends ErestaurantAppController {
    public $uses = array('Erestaurant.Categoria');

    public function index() {
        $this->Categoria->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('data', $this->Categoria->find('all'));
    }

    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Categoria->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Registro inválido.'));
        }
        /*
        $this->Categoria->recursive = -1;
        $options = array('conditions' => 
                            array('Categoria.'.$this->Categoria->primaryKey => $id),
                         'contain' => array(
                            'Plato' => array(
                                'Imagen'
                            )
                         )
                        );              
        */
        $this->Categoria->recursive = 2;
        $options = array('conditions' => 
                            array('Categoria.'.$this->Categoria->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('item', $this->Categoria->find('first', $options));


    }

}
```

The commented code you see it's another way I tried, using Containable, but at the end I get error "Plato is not associated with model Imagen"

Database seems all ok, with each table created as needed (categorias, platos, imagens, categorias_platos) and with all foering keys created and trying to keep CakePHP default names.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To access deep relations you must use **containable behavior**. You have a definition of containable behavior in your model, but for some reason it is commented.

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Uppon uncommenting this line in your Categoria, you can access deep relations in this way:

```
$this->Categoria->find('all', array(
    'contain'=>array(
        'Plato.Imagen'
    )
));
```

...or something like this. For more information plase visit this link [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

Comment: I started using Containable Behavior, but then i receive a message telling me Plato and Imagen models aren't asociated :(